# Markov chain from Poisson: null or positive recurrent?

Tags: probability, poisson-distribution, markov-process

Let $K_t$ be a Poisson process with rate $1$ and $X_n=K_n-n$ $,  \  \  \        n\in \mathbb{N}$

Now I want to determine whether it is null or positive recurrent, we already know it is recurrent.

I tried to compute the mean return time to zero, but, using the law of total probability, I got huge sums...

If $T=\min(n \geq 1 : X_n=0 |X_0 = 0) $ then I get:

$$ \mathbb{P}(T=k) = \sum_{t_1\not = 1}\sum _{t2\not = 2} \cdots \sum_{t_{k-1}\not = k-1} \mathbb{P}(K_1 = t_1)\mathbb{P}(K_2 = t_2)\cdots \mathbb{P}(K_{k-1}=t_{k-1})\mathbb{P}(N_k=k) $$

It does not look right....

How can I go on?

thank you very much